# Can A Graph Contain More Maximum Cliques Than Vertices?

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

A cycle on n vertices has n maximum cliques (i.e. K_2). [Except n=3]

Can you do better than this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. Any clique $K_n$ is non-bipartite for $n\geq 3$, thus any bipartite graph contains at most $K_1$ (which are isolated points) and $K_2$ cliques (which are edges).

Thus, your question can be answered by any bipartite graphs with more edges than vertices, say a [hypercube graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypercube_graph) of dimension $n \geq 3$.

I hope this helps $\ddot\smile$

Comment: Thanks I realised you could just add the chord to any long enough cycle!

Answer (score 2):

If $n$ is even, the union of $\frac n2$ disjoint copies of $K_2$ has $n$ vertices and $2^{\frac n2}$ maximal independent sets; its complement has $n$ vertices and $2^{\frac n2}$ maximal cliques. (Of course in this case the maximal cliques are also maxim**um** cliques.)

Comment: You could get even more by taking the complement of the disjoint union of $K_3$s, and that is the best you can do.